Filament importer jobs not running
I'm working on an app with a Filament backend. I'm currently trying to get an importer working. I've - added the queue:batches-tables (gave an "already exists" errror since it came with Jetstream already)

added the notification table
ran the filament-actions-migrations (all per the docs)
created an importer
I can upload a file. When I confirm the column mappings it gives a notification "x rows are being processed in the background"
... except nothing happens.

When I run the "php artisan queue:work"-command it does process the job but it still doesn't show any notifications (or provide the list of errors download-link).
I've added a dd('debug breakpoint') in the importer class > resolveRecord() function but it doesn't get triggered.
I'm a bit clueless here. I've had it working in the past with the same configuration. Can't tell what I'm missing here at this point?
thanks for any advice!
created an Filament Importer class & tried importing data
Excpected the import to happen but the job does not start

ok so I've debugged it down to the bus::batch() call in vendor/filament/concerns/CanImportCsv.php  this calls the job.
In jobs/importCsv.php it runs the __construct-class but the handle()-class is not called....

U have the latest version in filament (v3.2.73)? can u show some come? there is tutorials on community about implementing Filament Importer.

yeah I resolved it i the meantime. My listener-process was not running (I misunderstood the documentation and thought it was triggered from within the code)

...found it... I had to start the "php artisan queue:listen" command. I misunderstood the documentation and was under the impression the importCsv-job would trigger the batch execution. My bad :facepalm:
